# Rename multiple dataframe columns, referenced by current names

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I want to rename some random columns of a **large** data frame and I want to use the current column names, not the indexes. Column indexes might change if I add or remove columns to the data, so I figure using the existing column names is a more stable solution.
This is what I have now:

```
mydf = merge(df.1, df.2)
colnames(mydf)[which(colnames(mydf) == "MyName.1")] = "MyNewName"
```

Can I simplify this code, either the original `merge()` call or just the second line? `"MyName.1"` is actually the result of an xts `merge` of two different xts objects.

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible data set with the desired output?

Comment: You don't need the `which` there! R accepts boolean in the operator []. `colnames(mydf)[colnames(mydf)=="MyName.1"] = "MyNewName"` should work!

Comment: `names(mydf)[names(mydf) == "MyName.1"] = "MyNewName"` ...  about 13 or so characters shorter. Although, you may want to replace a vector in that case, use %in% instead of ==.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, could you repost your comment as an answer? In that way the community can see that the question is being addressed, and you'll get some rep for it.

Comment: I don't think this should not be tagged `data.table`, because this is about data frames (even though data tables are mentioned below).  The right way to rename columns in data table is by using `setnames`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
names(mydf)[names(mydf) == "MyName.1"] = "MyNewName" # 13 characters shorter.
```

Although, you may want to replace a vector eventually.  In that case, use `%in%` instead of `==` and set MyName.1 as a vector of equal length to MyNewName

Answer (score 155):

The trouble with changing column names of a `data.frame` is that, almost unbelievably, the entire `data.frame` is copied. Even when it's in `.GlobalEnv` and no other variable points to it.

The [`data.table` package](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) has a `setnames()` function which changes column names by reference without copying the whole dataset. `data.table` is different in that it doesn't copy-on-write, which can be very important for large datasets. (You did say your data set was large.). Simply provide the `old` and the `new` names:

```
require(data.table)
setnames(DT,"MyName.1", "MyNewName")
# or more explicit:
setnames(DT, old = "MyName.1", new = "MyNewName")
?setnames
```

Comment: Heh. That's a problem with doing almost anything to a `data.frame`. You'd think that just changing factor levels would be quick, too, but it's not. (I'm sure you of all people know that.)

Comment: @DWin. Hi. I think `setattrib()` in `data.table` could change levels of a column by reference (in a `data.frame`, too). Obviously needs to be done with care. There could be a new `setlevels()` function which would change one or many levels (with the same interface as `setnames()`)? Btw, `:=` already adds new factor levels by reference, which is tricky in base. There's quite a bit of C code behind that.

Comment: Just to note that you can update a list of names too, this is a handy snippet
`setnames(
  dt,
  names(dt),
  snakecase::to_snake_case(names(dt))
)`

Answer (score 27):

`plyr` has a rename function for just this purpose:

```
library(plyr)
mydf <- rename(mydf, c("MyName.1" = "MyNewName"))
```

Comment: This function is also now included in the `dplyr` package as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
names(mydf) <- sub("MyName\\.1", "MyNewName", names(mydf))
```

This would generalize better to a multiple-name-change strategy if you put a stem  as a pattern to be replaced using `gsub` instead of `sub`.

Comment: Thanks, this set me on the right path. I'm now doing: names(df)[grep(".1", names(df))] = c("AName.Col1", "AName.Col2", "AName.Col3")

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `str_replace` function of the [stringr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf) package:

```
names(mydf) <- str_replace(names(mydf), "MyName.1", "MyNewName")
```