# Refer function arguments with string names in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is a quick example of what I want:

"DF1" is the dataframe with two variables "V1" and "V2", so I can get the simple ggplot function as flows:

```
ggplot(DF1,aes(x=V1,y=V2))+geom_line()
```

Now, if I have the following two strings:

```
name1="V1"
name2="V2"
```

Is there a way to replace V1 and V2 with name1 and name2 in the above ggplot code? I tried to use do.call but didn't work out. I feel like I need formula-alike objective to do it.

Comment: only in plot? setNames before plot might work

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you mean something like setNames(V1, "name1") or setNames(DF1$V1, "name1")? I tried and it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the standard answer is

```
 aes_string(x=name1, y=name2)
```

(definitely a duplicate)

Comment: thanks @baptiste It seems that I did not search most efficiently with the right keyword

Comment: i can't find a duplicate either (though it's a FAQ), it's hard to search for

Answer (score 0):

I would rename column either using `plyr` along the line

```
library(plyr)
DF1 <- rename(DF1, c("V1" = "name1"))
```

or my preferable way, using `data.table`

```
require(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(DF1)
setnames(DT, "V1","name1")
```

then

```
ggplot(DT, aes(x=name1,y=name2))+geom_line()
```

Working with columns set to some `V1` etc is usually counterproductive and error-prone

UPDATE

some discussion [Named columns renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283171/named-columns-renaming)

Comment: thanks for your help @Severin Pappadeux. baptiste's way is easier so I'm giving him the credit.

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out that get() will work!

```
ggplot(DF1,aes(x=get(name1),y=get(name2)))+geom_line()
```

Comment: advice: don't use `get`

Comment: why is that? I never use it before

Comment: generally speaking, using `get` or `assign` is a clear sign that you're trying to do something following the pattern of another language, while in R there would be a more natural, elegant, safer way to "get" the same results. Closely related to `fortunes::fortune(236)`. Essentially, R encourages functional programming with lexical scoping, whereas `get` is too often used when you keep variables in the global environment (workspace). [not exactly the case here, but anyway]

Answer (score 0):

R base to change column name:

```
colnames(DF1)[colnames(DF1)=="V1"] <- "Name 1"
```